# Does Arduino use C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I see in one place that Arduino uses 'standard' C, and in another that it uses 'standard' C++, so on and so forth.

Which is it?

Comment: [C++ vs. The Arduino Language?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/816/3606)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Arduino sketches are written in C++.

Here is a typical construct you'll encounter:

```
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
...
lcd.begin(16, 2);
lcd.print("Hello, World!");
```

That's C++, not C.

Answer (score 23):

Both are supported. To quote the [Arduino homepage](http://code.google.com/p/arduino/),

> The core libraries are written in C and C++ and compiled using avr-gcc

Note that C++ is a superset of C (well, [almost](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#C-is-subset)), and thus can often look very similar. I am not an expert, but I guess that most of what you will program for the Arduino in your first year on that platform will not need anything but plain C.

Comment: C is indeed *almost* a subset of C++. However, non-shitty C code will look very different from non-shitty C++ code.

Comment: True, but non-shitty C code will *compile* as C++ (and C programs that are not C++ are shitty). Of course, good C++ code will not artificially and arbitrarily restrict itself to C.

Comment: Still nope. For instance, the [return value of `malloc` shouldn't be casted](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/395760) in C, yet in C++ it's mandatory. Now, allowing C++ to link and interact with C code is great, but for that you mostly need to avoid some reserved words and add a conditional (preprocessor) `extern "C"` *to the header*. That's quite a difference though. Also, there's a whole bunch of lovely C99 and C11 features which C++ does not support; why would good C code artificially restrict itself to a subset of C++?

Comment: @tiwo Non-shitty C code most definitely not compiles with a C++ compiler. For example, whenever you use *variable length arrays* it won't compile. Or whenever you use *structure literals*.