# I need a mix of strtok and strtok_single

Tags: c

I have the following string that I am trying to parse for variables.

```
char data[]="to=myself@gmail.com&cc=youself@gmail.com&title=&content=how are you?&signature=best regards."
```

I started with strtok and the following code

```
char *to=parsePostData("to",data);

char* parsePostData(char s[],char t[])
{
  char *postVal;
  char *pch;
  char tCpy[512];//Make a copy. Otherwise, strtok works on the char pointer, and original char array gets modified/ corrupted.
  strcpy(tCpy,t);
  pch = strtok (tCpy,"=&");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
      if(strcmp(pch,s)==0) {
            pch= strtok (NULL, "&");
                return pch;          
      }else{
        pch = strtok (NULL, "=&");  
      }
  }      
}
```

This works fine, except when it comes to consecutive delimiters such as the one after "title". So I found this custom strtok_single implementation. 
[Need to know when no data appears between two token separators using strtok()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705844/need-to-know-when-no-data-appears-between-two-token-separators-using-strtok)

```
char * strtok_single (char * str, char const * delims)
{
  static char  * src = NULL;
  char  *  p,  * ret = 0;

  if (str != NULL)
    src = str;

  if (src == NULL)
    return NULL;

  if ((p = strpbrk (src, delims)) != NULL) {
    *p  = 0;
    ret = src;
    src = ++p;
  }

  return ret;
}
```

But with this, the problem is I cannot get "signature", as there is no & delimiter after that.

How can I get a mix of this two, so I dont miss out the last variable, and I can handle consecutive delimiters?

Comment: Maybe look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807188/strtok-analogue-in-c?rq=1. This will split on both "=&" and "&" in one pass, though I guess you'll get a spurious blank on "=&", if I understand what they're doing correctly.

Comment: @mtrw I am working on arduino IDE. If possible I would like to not add more libraries for program size concerns. I hope there is a way to modify the above code to get the result, but if not I will look into the method you suggested.

Comment: @Cicada I am using Arduino IDE, and I am a beginner. I believe it uses C,C++  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11813275/903978

Comment: @Cicada, C would be better. thanks :)

Comment: I used this one and it works for me.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/3375658/903978

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two bugs lurking here.  One is in `strtok_single()`.  If you run it repeatedly, it does not return the last segment, after the `=` after signature, unlike `strtok()`.

When that's fixed, there is still a problem with the code in `parsePostData()`; it returns a pointer to an automatic variable.  The copy of the string must be handled differently; the simplest way (which is consistent with using `strtok()` rather than `strtok_r()` or `strtok_s()`) is to make the `tCpy` variable static.

#### Test program `emt.c`

This is a composite program that shows the problems and also a set of fixes.  It applies different 'splitter' functions — functions with the same signature as `strtok()` — to the data.  It demonstrates the bug in `strtok_single()` and that `strtok_fixed()` fixes that bug.  It demonstrates that the code in `parsePostData()` works correctly when it is fixed and `strtok_fixed()` is used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Function pointer for strtok, strtok_single, strtok_fixed */
typedef char *(*Splitter)(char *str, const char *delims);

/* strtok_single - as quoted in SO 30294129 (from SO 8705844) */
static char *strtok_single(char *str, char const *delims)
{
    static char  *src = NULL;
    char  *p,  *ret = 0;

    if (str != NULL)
        src = str;

    if (src == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if ((p = strpbrk(src, delims)) != NULL)
    {
        *p  = 0;
        ret = src;
        src = ++p;
    }

    return ret;
}

/* strtok_fixed - fixed variation of strtok_single */
static char *strtok_fixed(char *str, char const *delims)
{
    static char  *src = NULL;
    char  *p,  *ret = 0;

    if (str != NULL)
        src = str;

    if (src == NULL || *src == '\0')    // Fix 1
        return NULL;

    ret = src;                          // Fix 2
    if ((p = strpbrk(src, delims)) != NULL)
    {
        *p  = 0;
        //ret = src;                    // Unnecessary
        src = ++p;
    }
    else
        src += strlen(src);

    return ret;
}

/* Raw test of splitter functions */
static void parsePostData1(const char *s, const char *t, Splitter splitter)
{
    static char tCpy[512];
    strcpy(tCpy, t);
    char *pch = splitter(tCpy, "=&");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        printf("  [%s]\n", pch);
        if (strcmp(pch, s) == 0)
            printf("matches %s\n", s);
        pch = splitter(NULL, "=&");
    }
}

/* Fixed version of parsePostData() from SO 30294129 */
static char *parsePostData2(const char *s, const char *t, Splitter splitter)
{
    static char tCpy[512];
    strcpy(tCpy, t);
    char *pch = splitter(tCpy, "=&");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(pch, s) == 0)
        {
            pch = splitter(NULL, "&");
            return pch;
        }
        else
        {
            pch = splitter(NULL, "=&");
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

/* Composite test program */
int main(void)
{
    char data[] = "to=myself@gmail.com&cc=youself@gmail.com&title=&content=how are you?&signature=best regards.";
    char *tags[] = { "to", "cc", "title", "content", "signature" };
    enum { NUM_TAGS = sizeof(tags) / sizeof(tags[0]) };

    printf("\nCompare variants on strtok()\n");
    {
        int i = NUM_TAGS - 1;
        printf("strtok():\n");
        parsePostData1(tags[i], data, strtok);
        printf("strtok_single():\n");
        parsePostData1(tags[i], data, strtok_single);
        printf("strtok_fixed():\n");
        parsePostData1(tags[i], data, strtok_fixed);
    }

    printf("\nCompare variants on strtok()\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TAGS; i++)
    {
        char *value1 = parsePostData2(tags[i], data, strtok);
        printf("strtok: [%s] = [%s]\n", tags[i], value1);
        char *value2 = parsePostData2(tags[i], data, strtok_single);
        printf("single: [%s] = [%s]\n", tags[i], value2);
        char *value3 = parsePostData2(tags[i], data, strtok_fixed);
        printf("fixed:  [%s] = [%s]\n", tags[i], value3);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Example output from `emt`

```
Compare variants on strtok()
strtok():
  [to]
  [myself@gmail.com]
  [cc]
  [youself@gmail.com]
  [title]
  [content]
  [how are you?]
  [signature]
matches signature
  [best regards.]
strtok_single():
  [to]
  [myself@gmail.com]
  [cc]
  [youself@gmail.com]
  [title]
  []
  [content]
  [how are you?]
  [signature]
matches signature
strtok_fixed():
  [to]
  [myself@gmail.com]
  [cc]
  [youself@gmail.com]
  [title]
  []
  [content]
  [how are you?]
  [signature]
matches signature
  [best regards.]
```

And:

```
Compare variants on strtok()
✓ strtok: [to] = [myself@gmail.com]
✓ single: [to] = [myself@gmail.com]
✓ fixed:  [to] = [myself@gmail.com]
✓ strtok: [cc] = [youself@gmail.com]
✓ single: [cc] = [youself@gmail.com]
✓ fixed:  [cc] = [youself@gmail.com]
✕ strtok: [title] = [content=how are you?]
✓ single: [title] = []
✓ fixed:  [title] = []
✓ strtok: [content] = [how are you?]
✓ single: [content] = [how are you?]
✓ fixed:  [content] = [how are you?]
✓ strtok: [signature] = [best regards.]
✕ single: [signature] = [(null)]
✓ fixed:  [signature] = [best regards.]
```

The correct (✓ = U+2713) and incorrect (✕ = U+2715) marks were added manually when posting the answer.

Observe how only the lines tagged 'fixed' contain exactly what is wanted each time around.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't exactly told us what you mean by "this works fine", though it seems sufficient to say that you want to parse an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` string. Why didn't you say so in the first place?

Consider that the first field, `key`, may be terminated by the first of either `'='` or `'&'`. It would be appropriate to search for a token that ends in either of those characters, to extract `key`.

The second field, `value`, however, isn't terminated by an `'='` character, so it's inappropriate to be searching for that character to extract `value`. You'd want to search for `'&'` only.

Sure. You *could* use `strtok` to parse this, however I'm sure there are many more suitable tools. `strcspn`, for example, won't make any changes to `data`, which means you won't need to make a copy of `data` as you are...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char data[]="to=myself@gmail.com&cc=youself@gmail.com&title=&content=how are you?&signature=best regards.";

    char *key = data;
    do {
        int key_length = strcspn(key, "&=");

        char *value = key + key_length + (key[key_length] == '=');
        int value_length = strcspn(value, "&");

        printf("Key:   %.*s\n"
               "Value: %.*s\n\n",
               key_length,   key,
               value_length, value);

        key = value + value_length + (value[value_length] == '&');
    } while (*key);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: by 'it works fine', I meant it does the job of finding the value of the given key. Sorry, It did nt cross my mind that adding "application/x-www-form-urlencoded string" was important. Thanks very much for your answer

Comment: The way I see it is, if a piece of code occasionally fails, then that piece of code *doesn't work*...

Comment: Ok got it. To me, occassionally sounds more like unpredictable, which is different in my case as I know when it fails.