# read csv file to its end in c

Tags: c, csv, eof

So I have this code that reads a bunch of lines from a csv document. I know that initially the document has 16 rows, and that's why I designated `int noRows = 16;` in my main funtion.

```
void readBeer(int noRows) {
char *oneline, *token;
char oneproduct[256];
char delim[] = ",";
int x = 1;

FILE *fp; //open file
if ((fp = fopen("varor.csv", "r")) == NULL) //can the file be opened?
{
fprintf(stderr, "File varor.csv couldn't be opened\n"); //"couldn't open file"
exit(-1);
}

while(noRows != 0) 
{
    int countTok = 1;

    fgets(oneproduct, 256, fp); //get the first row
    oneproduct[strlen(oneproduct) - 1] = '\0'; // remove end-of-line character

    oneline = strdup(oneproduct); //duplicate oneproduct into oneline because strtok modifies the given string
    token = strtok(oneline, delim); //split oneline into tokens, tokens are separated by ","

    while (token != NULL) 
    {
        if(countTok == 1) beer[x].productNumber = atoi(token);
        else if(countTok == 2) strcpy(beer[x].name, token);
        else if(countTok == 3) beer[x].price = atof(token);
        else if(countTok == 4) beer[x].volume = atof(token);
        else if(countTok == 5) strcpy(beer[x].type, token);
        else if(countTok == 6) strcpy(beer[x].style, token);
        else if(countTok == 7) strcpy(beer[x].packaging, token);
        else if(countTok == 8) strcpy(beer[x].country, token);
        else if(countTok == 9) strcpy(beer[x].manufacturer, token);
        else if(countTok == 10) beer[x].alcohol = atof(token);
        else printf("kossan hoppade!"); //should never be seen in console
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        countTok++;
    }

    x++;
    noRows--;
    free(oneline); free(token);

}

fclose(fp);
```

}

My question is how do I read the file to its end without first knowing how many rows it has? I'm thinking of having a specific cell in the file just to save `noRows` between startup and shutdown of console.

I tried using `char buffer[1000]; while(fgets(buffer, 1000, fp)) {}` but then it reads the first 8 rows(not sure if it's always exactly 8) as 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.

Comment: Did you try to check whether you reached EOF? BTW: Are you sure that the last line holding values contains a `\n` at the end?

Comment: Please, use switch(), so many else if-s look terrible.

Comment: When I used the buffer, it stopped after the last line, so it registered the EOF, yeah. What does the \n matter on the last line?

Comment: @Gnqz I usually want it to work before I make it look good, but I'll edit it.

Comment: You always remove the last character of a read line. If the last line does not end with `\n`, you remove one character of your "payload". Text files where last line does not end with `\n` are quite usual (i.e. may occur more often as you imagine as you usually cannot see this in the text editors).

Comment: Regarding your actual question: Your attempt to re-design is promising. Try [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) instead of `fgets()`. it returns `-1` if it fails.

Comment: The `free(token)` is IMHO wrong. It probably has no negative effect as it is always left with `NULL` after a row has been processed. `strtok()` does not allocate new storage. Instead, it modifies the original string (which is passed at first call).

Comment: Concerning `strtok()`: I once posted a variation of `strtok()` as answer to [SO: Split string into Tokens in C, when there are 2 delimiters in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42315689/7478597). It works quite similar like `strtok()` and may illustrate how "they" probably do it internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question if *just test the return value of fgets*

```
for (;;)   // idiomatic C style for an infinite loop 
{
    int countTok = 1;

    if (NULL == fgets(oneproduct, 256, fp)) break; //get one row and exit loop on EOF
    ...
```

But as you were told in comments, there are many other problems in your code:

- you initialize your indexes to 1 while C array indexes start at 0. So I assume that `x=1;` should be `x=0;`. For the same reason, `countTok = 1;` is not wrong, but `countTok = 0;` would be more idiomatic C
- you use `fprintf(stderr, ...` to notice an error when opening the file. While not wrong, it gives no indication on the cause of the error. `perror` would do...
- you erase last character of `oneproduct` without controling it is a newline. The assumption will be wrong

  - if one line contains at least 256 characters
  - if last line does not end with a newline

  The idiomatic way is to use `strcspn`:

  ```
  oneproduct[strcspn(oneproduct, "\n")] = '\0';  // erase an optional end of line
  ```
- you duplicate `oneproduct` to `oneline`. Here again, nothing is wrong, but it is useless because you never use the original line
- the long list of `else if` could be replaced with a switch, but this one is mainly a matter of style
- you free `token` at the end of loop. As it is NULL it is a no-op, but it is was not allocated it should not be freed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `fgets`, you can test if the result of the call is equal to `NULL` or not.`fgets` signals `NULL` on error or `EOF` (end-of-file).

`char *fgets(char *line, int maxline, FILE *fp);`.

I.E:

```
while (fgets(buffer, MAXLINE, fp) != NULL) {
    // Process line here.
}
```

You can also process the entire file character by character and test if `(c == EOF)`. There are a couple of ways to do it.